# SP2010: Why are individual user accounts appearing in group list

Tags: groups, user

SharePoint 2010

I go to site settings and People and Groups, click on Groups on the quick launch to view all user groups.

In the list of groups, there are more than a few user accounts that are displayed and I'm not sure why.  I've deleted a user account from the site collection and added them back in to a group, and that account will appear again in the group list.

My team member who's in charge of managing accounts noticed this and said she had added 150 or users to different groups, and randomly 20 or so of them would appear in the group list.

Here is a partial screenshot of what I'm talking about.  The top three are groups, bottom two are user accounts.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Screen shot added.

Comment: These are users, not AD user groups, or distro groups?

Comment: The groups were created from the site level and are not AD or distro groups.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the user accounts that are blacked out, these are in fact user accounts and not AD groups posing as user accounts?

Comment: Hmm..they should be user accounts however the accounts are created in AD by another team so I'm not all so sure.  Is there a way I could verify from the site or SPD?

Comment: Click on it? Not sure if it'll be that simple. I don't know if you can determine the user type through the UI, should be able to through PowerShell or code.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to check. 
On which page you are getting this, Site permissions...Url ends with this "/_layouts/user.aspx"? if yes then expected behavior

or on the people & groups page with url Ending "/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=2"? if yes then you are in some group

Or on the people & groups page with url Ending "/_layouts/groups.aspx" page? if yes then that's the problem.

Comment: The URL does end with "/_layouts/groups.aspx".  Is this then not the correct page to view ONLY user groups?  And I'm guessing this is not an issue or concern, where random accounts appear in the group list.